# SetFullscreenState not returning

Tags: windows, winapi, fullscreen, rust

When I call the [`IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreenState`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiswapchain-setfullscreenstate) method, it does not return. The window goes fullscreen, but accepts no further input. A `println!()` put right after never fires. I am assuming there is some sort of deadlock happening behind the scenes, but the docs don't go into what all it locks.

- Does `SetFullscreenState` perform any locking?
- If so, what does it lock?
- What other issues could cause `SetFullscreenState` to never return?

I am using Rust 1.44.1 with `winapi` 0.3.9. I am passing `minwindef::TRUE` and a null pointer as arguments (passing `minwindef::FALSE` returns, but does the opposite of what I want). I am using the following options in the swapchain desc:

```
desc.BufferCount = 1;
desc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
desc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
desc.BufferDesc.Format = dxgiformat::DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
desc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
desc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
desc.BufferUsage = dxgitype::DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
desc.OutputWindow = *hwnd.inner();
desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
desc.Flags = dxgi::DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;
desc.Windowed = minwindef::TRUE;
```

Comment: Where did you get the refresh rate numbers from?  Did you enumerate them via DXGI or did you just hard-code for 60?  There are some additional constraints around DXGI and you really should be using properly enumerated refresh rates if you're not already doing so - otherwise you may be masking other problems.

Comment: The numbers came from the tutorial I was following. They are hard-coded. I'll look into fixing those.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue.

Before returning, `SetFullscreenState` sends a `WM_MOVE` *then* a `WM_SIZE` to the event loop. I was only paying attention to the `WM_SIZE`, which never got called because my version of `WM_MOVE` blocked.